# Instantiating Stucts and Arrays doesn't create new references

Tags: go

I'm attempting to convert a simple markdown file into json, the markdown looks something like this:

```
#TITLE 1
- Line 1
- Line 2
- Line 3

#TITLE 2
- Line 1
- Line 2
- Line 3
<!-- blank line -->
```

I can't understand what's required to refactor the following in **func main()**:

```
    type Section struct {
        Category string
        Lines    []string
    }

    file, _ := os.Open("./src/basicmarkdown/basicmarkdown.md")

    defer file.Close()

    rgxRoot, _ := regexp.Compile("^#[^#]")
    rgxBehaviour, _ := regexp.Compile("^-[ ]?.*")

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    ruleArr := []*Section{}
    rule := &Section{}

    for scanner.Scan() {

        linetext := scanner.Text()

        // If it's a blank line
        if rgxRoot.MatchString(linetext) {
            rule := &Section{}
            rule.Category = linetext
        }

        if rgxBehaviour.MatchString(linetext) {
            rule.Lines = append(rule.Lines, linetext)
        }

        if len(strings.TrimSpace(linetext)) == 0 {
            ruleArr = append(ruleArr, rule)
        }

    }

    jsonSection, _ := json.MarshalIndent(ruleArr, "", "\t")
    fmt.Println(string(jsonSection))
```

The code above outputs:

```
[
{
        "Category": "",
        "Lines": [
            "- Line 1",
            "- Line 2",
            "- Line 3",
            "- Line 1",
            "- Line 2",
            "- Line 3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Category": "",
        "Lines": [
            "- Line 1",
            "- Line 2",
            "- Line 3",
            "- Line 1",
            "- Line 2",
            "- Line 3"
        ]
    }
]
```

When I was hoping to output:

```
[
    {
        "Category": "#TITLE 1",
        "Lines": [
            "- Line 1",
            "- Line 2",
            "- Line 3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Category": "#TITLE 2",
        "Lines": [,
            "- Line 1",
            "- Line 2",
            "- Line 3"
        ]
    }
]
```

Couple of things wrong for sure. Please excuse the verbosity of the question, hard to explain without an example when you're a noob. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it's only for the sake of the example but please always check your errors. Assigning them to _ will never make your life better.

Comment: Thanks Snowman, you're correct, it was for the sake of the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `for` loop, take a closer look to this part:

```
// If it's a blank line
if rgxRoot.MatchString(linetext) {
    rule := &Section{} // Notice the `:=`
    rule.Category = linetext
}
```

You're basically creating a new `rule` variable in the scope of that `if`, when you probably want to reuse the one you have already created outside the `for` loop.

So, try changing it to:

```
// If it's a blank line
if rgxRoot.MatchString(linetext) {
    rule = &Section{} // Notice the `=`
    rule.Category = linetext
}
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks kindly noisypixy, I can sleep tonight! Regards.